# CSS grid not considering min value in minmax along with auto-fit

Tags: css, css-grid

Hi Im trying to create responsive column with the behaviour.
The width of the column can go between 335px or 540px.

But when i use `grid-template-columns: repeat(auto-fit, minmax(335px, 540px))` it seems only the 540px is taken into consideration.

Like if there is 700px available, i would like 3 items laid out in 2 columns.

```css
.box {
  display: grid;
  grid-template-columns: repeat(auto-fit, minmax(335px, 540px));
  grid-gap: 10px;
  row-gap: 10px;
}

.item {
  background: red;
}
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
  <meta charset="utf-8">
  <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width">
  <title>JS Bin</title>
</head>
<body>
  <div class="box">
    <div class="item item1">1</div>
    <div class="item item2">2</div>
    <div class="item item3">3</div>
  </div>
</body>
</html>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Consider `max-width` on your elements instead and use `1fr` inside the `minmax()`

```css
.box {
  display: grid;
  grid-template-columns: repeat(auto-fit, minmax(335px, 1fr));
  grid-gap: 10px;
}

.item {
  background: red;
  max-width: 540px;
}
```

```html
<div class="box">
  <div class="item item1">1</div>
  <div class="item item2">2</div>
  <div class="item item3">3</div>
</div>
```