# Why are new rows being created before items shrink?

Tags: css, css-grid

I'm trying to create a grid that shrinks items before creating new rows.  Instead, it always creates new rows and never shrinks items.

```css
.grid {
  display: grid;
  grid-template-columns: repeat(auto-fit, minmax(150px, 200px));
  justify-content: center;
  justify-items: center;
  grid-gap: 2em;
}

.grid > div {
  background: grey;
  min-height: 150px;
  min-width: 150px;
}
```

```html
<div class="grid">
  <div></div>
  <div></div>
  <div></div>
  <div></div>
  <div></div>
  <div></div>
  <div></div>
  <div></div>
  <div></div>
</div>
```

Here is a photo of the grid 1px before shrinking it would lead to new rows:

[image]

As you can see, there is plenty of room around the content in each cell.  That content is 150px wide.  The grid cell is 200px wide, the top end of its minmax, but refuses to get any smaller.  It should shrink down to 150px before creating any new rows.

Everything I've read online or asked from AI has stated I'm doing this right.  I'm using Opera GX, which does support this feature.

Comment: Found the duplicate:  https://stackoverflow.com/questions/59142033/css-grid-not-considering-min-value-in-minmax-along-with-auto-fit

The issue is that minmax() appears not to work with a max set to a px unit.

Comment: Probably because the track sizes are calculated **first** based on the max size of the grid items. The flexibility of the items comes after these container lengths are fixed. Check the [track sizing algorithm](https://www.w3.org/TR/css3-grid-layout/#algo-track-sizing).

Comment: [Same behavior in flexbox](https://jsfiddle.net/Lbmax8fs/).

Comment: minmax() will always default to the max value if possible and only use the min if not. So you will always have 200px until you reach one column

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/q/50654400/3597276

Comment: Ah.  So priority is to make things as big as possible, not to fit as many things on the screen as possible.  The question linked by Michael shows the solution.

Answer (score -2):

I am not sure if this can answer your question, but you can try using clamp() for a sort of responsiveness. I used it for width and height. You can change values according to your needs. You can check [clamp()](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/clamp)

```css
.grid {
  display: grid;
  grid-template-columns: repeat(auto-fit, minmax(150px,200px));
  justify-content: center;
  justify-items: center;
  grid-gap: 2em;
}

.grid > div {
  display: flex;
  background: grey;
  min-height: clamp(150px,15vw,200px);
  min-width: clamp(150px,15vw,200px);
}

.shrink{
  display: flex;
  width: 100%;
}
```

```html
<div class="grid">
    <div></div>
    <div></div>
    <div></div>
    <div></div>
    <div></div>
    <div></div>
    <div></div>
    <div></div>
    <div></div>
  </div>
```